# Room with Flow and RecyclerView with ListAdapter

Tags: android-recyclerview, android-room, kotlin-coroutines, listadapter, kotlin-flow

I have a Large Dataset in Room and it want to show it on RecyclerView but the app freezes due to huge dataset.

I am using Dao -> Repository -> ViewModel -> Activity/Fragment (To show in RecyclerView using ListAdapter)

Dao:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
fun getAllFlowItems(): Flow<List<Item>>
```

Repository:

```
fun getAllFlowItems(): Flow<List<Item>> {
    return dao.getAllFlowItems()
}
```

ViewModel:

```
fun getAllFlowItems(): Flow<List<Item>> {
    return repository.getAllFlowItems()
}
```

MainActivity/Fragment:

```
lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
    viewModel.getAllFlowItems().collectLatest() {
        adapter.submitList(it)
    }
}
```